# How to create Quiz Application using Google App Script(GAS)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api, google-sites

I am newbie to Google App Scripting(GAS). I need to make app for Quiz using Google App Script(GAS). It is possible to make such application in Google App Script.

I have a list of questions, associated options and correct answer in Google Spreadsheet. I have to integrate this question and options in randomize fashion with Google form and generates the response at runtime and store these responses in other google spreadsheet.

It is possible to do this in Google App Scripting(GAS).

Comment: Yes it is. You need to know how to program. Look at the tutorials and documentation. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/‎ ... Or ... I do have a way to do this with spreadsheet formulas, I am looking for early adopters.

Answer (score 2):

I've looked at developing a quiz in the past and I eventually settled on [flubaroo.com](http://www.flubaroo.com) which has been set up as an open source project even though the source code is now hidden when you download it as an add-on. You can get an older version of the code that doesn't have a lot missing if you insert the script to an old type of Google spreadsheet. It doesn't have the randomised question feature you are after though.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible with Google Apps Script?

Yes, now it's possible a Google extended the [Forms Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/) as was announced on April, 2017.

Reference

[Create quizzes in Google Forms with Apps Script](https://gsuite-developers.googleblog.com/2017/04/create-quizzes-in-google-forms-with.html)

Answer (score 0):

why you don't use Google Forms ?
you can Add questions , and  solutions, and your data will save in the spreadsheet.

In Google App Script , it's possible but , you must make an UI Application , with good interface , with Css.
Put your questions and  solutions in your spreadsheet , and take a loop  randomised to save a number of the question and show question.